# Django models does not create table after I clone it on github

Tags: python, django, django-models

Recently I'm doing a small Django project that I have to work with my teammates,
so I clone the project's repository from github.
The problem is , the database in my computer doesn't have the table so i think i have to makemigrations and migrate it. But after i did that,django only createed its own tables but didn't create other tables that my teammates wrote in Django's models.
I really need your guys hlep

[this are the models my teammates wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShRkP.jpg)

but after i makemigrations and migrate it ,phpmyadmin does not show the tables i want
[makemigrations and migrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPMiL.jpg)

[the picture on phpmyadmin after I migrate django models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZxnJ.jpg)

[This is my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L43DT.jpg)

[after tried this,it still not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRqft.jpg)

[migrations folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73wBR.jpg)

Comment: have you installed the app in settings.py which has this models??

Comment: hello, yes I did

Comment: can you please show what is in myapp>migrations> folder

Comment: ok  no problem ,please wait

Comment: try to delete this migrations file and then try again. Note: Create new database

Comment: hi ! after i deleted the folder and migrate again , now the folder won't spawn again , it's that normal?

Comment: you can try `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>`

Comment: thank you! you help me a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use managed=True in all models for managing the migrations via django

Comment: ok i'll try it!

Comment: do you mean changing managed=True in models' meta?

Comment: thank you a lot ! it was solved!

Comment: Yes, it's part of model meta.

Answer (score -1):

run

```
python manage.py makemigrations *name_of_you_app_that_has_models_here*
python manage.py migrate *name_of_you_app_that_has_models_here*
```